# Get data from SocketActivityTriggerDetails with DatagramSocket

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

From an example of the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background), I try to retrieve the received data from **DatagramSocket** in my background task with the socket broker and the **SocketActivityTrigger**.

But the example shown in the link is for **StreamSocket** :

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SocketActivityTriggerDetails;
    var socketInformation = details.SocketInformation;
    switch (details.Reason)
    {
        case SocketActivityTriggerReason.SocketActivity:
            var socket = socketInformation.StreamSocket; 
            DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream); 
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial; 
            await reader.LoadAsync(250); 
            var dataString = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            break;
    }
}
```

I can not find the received data from [DatagramSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241319) object, we only have access to the output stream..

How can I do ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I can not find the received data from DatagramSocket object, we only have access to the output stream..

For `DatagramSocket` object, when we need to receive data, we need to  fitstly register its [MessageReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.messagereceived.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and then in its [DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocketmessagereceivedeventargs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), we can use its [GetDataReader method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocketmessagereceivedeventargs.getdatareader.aspx) to get the transferred data.

For background task, code is similar to the [official Socket activity trigger stream socket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket). But for `DatagramSocket`, we need to register this `MessageReceived` event and handle the data in the background task.

Just for example here:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    try
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SocketActivityTriggerDetails;
        var socketInformation = details.SocketInformation;
        switch (details.Reason)
        {
            case SocketActivityTriggerReason.SocketActivity:
                var socket = socketInformation.DatagramSocket;
                socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ShowToast(exception.Message);
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}

private void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    using (var reader = args.GetDataReader())
    {
        //TODO: read data here.
    }
}
```

Comment: @grace-feng-msft Thank you for your reply but.. I think you don't understand the behavior behind the **SocketActivityTrigger**.
In fact, the broker socket take ownership of the DatagramSocket we create in foreground and when it receives a packet it starts the background task. So.. subscribe to MessageReceived event **is too late**, the packet was already received :(

Comment: Nobody else can help me?

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache No, I dropped that approach and I went around the problem differently. But I'll be interested to know if this bug has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

You must call EnableOwnerShip, TransferOwnerShip methods after bindServiceName or bindEndPoint. I'm working now this subject..

Answer (score 0):

@grace-feng-mst's answer is accurate. The DatagramSocket's ownership is transferred back to the app as soon as you do:

```
var socket = socketInformation.DatagramSocket;
```

After that, you're supposed to register a MessageReceived handler to read the received data. The DatagramSocket class doesn't have an InputStream property; it follows an event-based model for incoming I/O.

Even though the **SocketActivityTrigger** raises the background task when a datagram arrives, it doesn't drain the socket. The data will still be there, waiting for the app to register a MessageReceived handler.

One key thing missing from @grace-feng-mst's answer is the transfer of the socket back to the broker:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    try
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SocketActivityTriggerDetails;
        var socketInformation = details.SocketInformation;
        switch (details.Reason)
        {
            case SocketActivityTriggerReason.SocketActivity:
                var socket = socketInformation.DatagramSocket;
                socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;

                // Wait for data to be read by MessageReceived handler (e.g., waiting on an event that is signaled by the handler).
                // Write some data.

                // Transfer socket ownership back to the broker.
                await socket.CancelIOAsync();
                socket.TransferOwnership(…);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ShowToast(exception.Message);
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}

private void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    using (var reader = args.GetDataReader())
    {
        //TODO: read data here.
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that the above code works as expected. An external user also confirmed this (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/958)).

Comment: So you say that the event is not triggered until we have hooked a method to it? It seems pretty twisted as behavior but I will test tonight if I find my old project ahah! 
I'll keep you informed, thanks 

Comment: Yes, the DatagramSocket's data only gets drained when there's at least one registered MessageReceived handler ;)